# Wget -P usage under Windows with path which contains some space char

Tags: batch-file, path, wget

I try to use wget with the -P option to specify the output path where file(s) will be downloaded. But I meet some problems when there are some spaces in the path.
I have tried several ways to solve it but without any success.

These examples don't work :

```
wget -N --tries=3 --timeout=5 --random-wait "https://xxx" -P="\\NAS\folder with space"

wget -N --tries=3 --timeout=5 --random-wait "https://xxx" -P='\\NAS\folder with space'

wget -N --tries=3 --timeout=5 --random-wait "https://xxx" -P=\\NAS\folder\ with\ space

wget -N --tries=3 --timeout=5 --random-wait "https://xxx" -P=\\NAS\folder%20with%20space
```

PS : these examples are executed from a windows batch file

Comment: Try without the equal sign between `-P"\\NAS\folder with space"`

Comment: I tested @LotPings syntax and that is correct.  I also tested putting the whole path in the -O option and that worked as well. But I believe that is just for a single file.  Your other option would be to use `PUSHD` and `POPD` before and after the `WGET` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Squashman. The POPD/PUSHD is very useful and allow me to execute the bach file stored in the NAS directly from my Windows computer. So, by using the `pushd %~dp0` I can start a download process in the same directory the batch file is. That's powerfull !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cite from `wget --help`

```
 Directories:
  -nd, --no-directories           don't create directories.
  -x,  --force-directories        force creation of directories.
  -nH, --no-host-directories      don't create host directories.
       --protocol-directories     use protocol name in directories.
  -P,  --directory-prefix=PREFIX  save files to PREFIX/...
       --cut-dirs=NUMBER          ignore NUMBER remote directory components.
```

I read it that way that the single letter (single dash) options don't need a delimiter from the value,
while the different length verbose ones need the equal sign.

(All single dash, dual letter options are switches without a value)

Comment: That's clear ! Maybe, I will have to change my glasses ! Thanks a lot.